# Tensorflow 2.0 GPU does not display output(Possible crash)

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I have a Windows 10 system with a GeForce 930 MX NVIDIA Graphics card, CUDA 10.0, CudNN 7.6.3, and `tensorflow 2.0-gpu` . I'm trying to do Object Detection using this link: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection
 My output does not give errors although crashes and does not complete. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import six.moves.urllib as urllib
import sys
import tarfile
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile
import cv2

from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from IPython.display import display
from object_detection.utils import ops as utils_ops
from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as vis_util
#tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)
physical_devices = tf.compat.v1.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU') 

tf.compat.v1.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)

utils_ops.tf = tf.compat.v1
print(utils_ops.tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU'))

# Patch the location of gfile
tf.gfile = tf.io.gfile

def load_model(model_name):
  base_url = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/'
  model_file = model_name + '.tar.gz'
  model_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    fname=model_name, 
    origin=base_url + model_file,
    untar=True)

  model_dir = pathlib.Path(model_dir)/"saved_model"

  model = tf.saved_model.load(str(model_dir))
  model = model.signatures['serving_default']

  return model




# List of the strings that is used to add correct label for each box.
PATH_TO_LABELS = 'data/mscoco_label_map.pbtxt'
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS, use_display_name=True)



import pathlib
PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR = pathlib.Path('test_images')
TEST_IMAGE_PATHS = sorted(list(PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR.glob("*.jpg")))
model_name = 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17'
detection_model = load_model(model_name)

def run_inference_for_single_image(model, image):
  image = np.asarray(image)
  # The input needs to be a tensor, convert it using `tf.convert_to_tensor`.
  input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(image)
  # The model expects a batch of images, so add an axis with `tf.newaxis`.
  input_tensor = input_tensor[tf.newaxis,...]

  # Run inference
  output_dict = model(input_tensor)

  # All outputs are batches tensors.
  # Convert to numpy arrays, and take index [0] to remove the batch dimension.
  # We're only interested in the first num_detections.
  num_detections = int(output_dict.pop('num_detections'))
  output_dict = {key:value[0, :num_detections].numpy() 
                 for key,value in output_dict.items()}
  output_dict['num_detections'] = num_detections

  # detection_classes should be ints.
  output_dict['detection_classes'] = output_dict['detection_classes'].astype(np.int64)

  # Handle models with masks:
  if 'detection_masks' in output_dict:
    # Reframe the the bbox mask to the image size.
    detection_masks_reframed = utils_ops.reframe_box_masks_to_image_masks(
              output_dict['detection_masks'], output_dict['detection_boxes'],
               image.shape[0], image.shape[1])      
    detection_masks_reframed = tf.cast(detection_masks_reframed > 0.5,
                                       tf.uint8)
    output_dict['detection_masks_reframed'] = detection_masks_reframed.numpy()

  return output_dict

def show_inference(model, image_path):
  # the array based representation of the image will be used later in order to prepare the
  # result image with boxes and labels on it.
  image_np = np.array(Image.open(image_path))
  # Actual detection.
  output_dict = run_inference_for_single_image(model, image_np)
  # Visualization of the results of a detection.
  vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
      image_np,
      output_dict['detection_boxes'],
      output_dict['detection_classes'],
      output_dict['detection_scores'],
      category_index,
      instance_masks=output_dict.get('detection_masks_reframed', None),
      use_normalized_coordinates=True,
      line_thickness=8)

  cv2.imshow(Image.fromarray(image_np))
  print("OK!")

for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
    show_inference(detection_model, image_path)
```

Here is the output:

```
(tfflask) C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\models-master\research\object_detection>python test_object.py
2020-06-04 19:15:31.227206: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_100.dll
2020-06-04 19:15:33.830860: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2020-06-04 19:15:34.246286: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1618] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce 930MX major: 5 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.0195
pciBusID: 0000:03:00.0
2020-06-04 19:15:34.251302: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dlopen_checker_stub.cc:25] GPU libraries are statically linked, skip dlopen check.
2020-06-04 19:15:34.258134: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1746] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
2020-06-04 19:15:35.890465: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2020-06-04 19:15:35.966988: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1618] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce 930MX major: 5 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.0195
pciBusID: 0000:03:00.0
2020-06-04 19:15:35.980010: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dlopen_checker_stub.cc:25] GPU libraries are statically linked, skip dlopen check.
2020-06-04 19:15:35.991055: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1746] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-06-04 19:15:37.099838: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1159] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-06-04 19:15:37.102595: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1165]      0
2020-06-04 19:15:37.104199: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1178] 0:   N
2020-06-04 19:15:37.109167: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1304] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 1384 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce 930MX, pci bus id: 0000:03:00.0, compute capability: 5.0)
2020-06-04 19:15:43.916571: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-06-04 19:15:44.713084: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/redzone_allocator.cc:312] Internal: Invoking ptxas not supported on Windows
Relying on driver to perform ptx compilation. This message will be only logged once.
2020-06-04 19:15:45.661495: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:239] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.06GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2020-06-04 19:15:45.930582: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:239] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.09GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2020-06-04 19:15:46.118122: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:239] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.15GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2020-06-04 19:15:46.517654: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:239] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.27GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
```

I can't seem to figure out why it's crashing, I tried using CuDnn 7.4.1 and 7.4.2 and it gave an error that looked something like:
`CuDNN failed to initialize`
It seems to not give that error with 7.6.3 but however, it crashes without output. Pls, Help!

Comment: It is likely that the problem is that your GPU does not have enough RAM, 1.3 GB is very small, something like 4 GB is kind of the minimum.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy is there a way to make tensorflow use up less memory equal to the size of the card? I've run other operations using the gpu and it works just fine

Comment: Memory usage depends on the model, a smaller model will work, but a big one will not, and object detection models are just not small.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I figured out the solution(yet not the problem). I upgraded to tensorflow-gpu-2.2 (latest) and updated by gpu driver and now it runs like a charm